# How to display a numeric Two dimensional array in JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm having the following code to print an array in the console log it returns the expected value in line but when in innerHtml it just does not print as if it were an Two dimensional array

```js
   
    var matrix = [];
    for(var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [];
        for(var j=0; j<2; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i;
              document.getElementById('hassianaJ').innerHTML += '<tr><th scope="row">' +matrix[i][j] + '</th></tr>';

        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
      <table class="table">
          <thead id="hassiamaI">

          </thead>
          <tbody id="hassianaJ">
          
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You does not close the `<th>` element.

Comment: sorry my mistake. Edited

Comment: It should work now (: although there is still a mismatched `<head>` element as @bambam mentioned.

Comment: Although I believe the practice sloppy, It should be noted `<th>` doesn't need the end tag `</th>` if it is followed by `<th>` or `<td>`. In this case the OP was entirely wrong closing a `<th>` with a `</td>` before edit. @aydinugur should answer with more details otherwise this answer makes no sense and OP should edit and add a note that there's an edit to question and if it solved or not. This is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @zer00ne I agree with you about `<th>` element closing and OP part as well.